# Decide which procedure to call, depending on field value

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.2

I have about 20 (and there will be more) specific stored procedures in my PostgreSQL 9.2 DB. They are used to make some calculations, some kind of financial "reports" (unfortunately, I can't just store data in tables and implement algorithms in the programs's code).

Procedures are very different one from another, they're operating on different tables, columns, implementing different algorithms etc.

Every procedure returns the same data type (numeric value).

And now, my client wants to create the funcionality, where user can select specific procedure (or combination of them, e.g. 10% of procedure's 1 returning value + 90% of procedure's 2 returning value), and use it as a "base" for later modeling.
He wants also my user to be able to change his selection later, without calling programmers every time. ;-)

I thought about making some tables:

```
Table: base_models
id <PK>,
user_id, <FK from users table>
model_name (varchar, or sth.)


Table: base_models_algorithms
base_model_id <FK from base_models>
algorithm_id <FK from algorithms>
percent_value (percent value of specific algorithm in model, eg. 10)
```

...and then, I need to store also my algorithm names (= stored procedures) in some table:

```
Table: algorithms
name: (stored procedure name, varchar?)
```

... and that's where the problem is.

Of course I can later create some view, with a column calculated by another procedure (model_current_value :-)), and decide what procedure to call depending on name stored in my algorithm's table, but that look awful for me. :(

There would be no data control (you can write anything to algorithms' table, and there is no way to ensure that this string is a name of procedure, returning correct data type etc.).

Of course I can fill the table myself, and won't let anyone to change it's data :-)

But maybe there is more elegant way to do the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE` statement. You can use this to invoke dynamic SQL, eg for a 2-argument procedure with dynamic name:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %I($1,$2)', func_name) USING arg1, arg2;
```

This is a PL/PgSQL statement. It is not available in regular SQL. You can of course create a simple PL/PgSQL procedure that does this statement and call that from SQL.